# Using a repeated delimiter to mark both the start and end of section

Tags: regex

I'm no regex expert, but I have colleagues who treat me as one and ask me for help with their regex problems.  This one stumped me today, and I don't think it should have.  (I don't know exactly what flavor of regex the colleague is using, so I guess any common regex format would do for an answer!)

How could I extract the sections of data separated by a single delimiter between them?  Can this be done in a single regex? For example:

```
**********
some data
here
**********
is broken into
*sections* by
**********
the repeated
**********
blocks of asterisks
**********
```

This has the delimiter of `"**********"` (`\*{10}`), and a global regex should return the values `["some data\nhere", "is broken into\n*sections* by", "the repeated", "blocks of asterisks"]`.

I can easily get **[something that matches](http://regex101.com/r/hW2rZ7/1)** alternating blocks via:

```
/(?:^|\n)\*{10}\n([\s\S]*?)\n\*{10}(?:\n|\$)/g
//=> ["some data\nhere", "the repeated"]
```

But as the first match "uses up" the second instance of the delimiter, it's not available to be the beginning of the second one.

Is there a simple regex way to do this?

Comment: What is your expected output from this regex?

Comment: If you want to break up your matches on a line-by-line basis between the delimiters, even if the block of data is more than one line, you can use this. It grabs the whole line so long as it isn't 10 asterisks.

    (?m)^(?!\*{10}).*

Changed from Answer to Comment, as it was intended to be more of a footnote comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... The easiest way is to split on `\*{10,}`, but if your tool doesn't let you do this, you could try the following:

```
\s*\*{10,}\s*(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:.(?!\*{10}))+
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mO8pQ3/4)

Since you let us use any flavour in the answers, that's a Perl/PCRE only regex.

Or this if you need simpler syntax:

```
(?:\*{10,}\s*)?((?:.(?!\*{10}))+)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mO8pQ3/5). Result is in `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this

```
(?s:(?:\*{10}|.)(.*?)\*{10}|(.*?)\*{10}|(.*?))
```

although I'm not sure of which format you want exactly. The proposed regex throws the tokens in the group 1.

Cheers!